# I have a dialog box that launches a video if "yes" is selected. The video launches and plays but when it's done, the dialog still remains

Tags: android, video, dialog

I'm writing an android program to show a dialog and based on the button clicked in the dialog it shows or doesn't show a video. When the user clicks the yes button, it plays. But the dialog is still there when it ends. Why?

Code for the dialog

```
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    //builder.setTitle(" MY_TEXT");
    builder.setMessage("Would you like to see a video?")
    .setView(checkBoxView)
    .setCancelable(false)
    .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
            //Start the movie
            startVideo();
            dialog.cancel();
        }
    })
    .setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
            dialog.cancel();
        }
    }).show().getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DIM_BEHIND);
```

Code for the video

```
    getWindow().setFormat(PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);
    final VideoView videoHolder = new VideoView(this);
    //if you want the controls to appear
    videoHolder.setMediaController(new MediaController(this));
    Uri video = Uri.parse("android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/" 
            + R.raw.documentariesandyou); //do not add any extension
    //if your file is named sherif.mp4 and placed in /raw
    //use R.raw.sherif
    videoHolder.setVideoURI(video);
    setContentView(videoHolder);
    videoHolder.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {

        @Override
        public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
            //exits video!
            videoHolder.stopPlayback();
            mp.release();
            finish();
        }
    });
    videoHolder.start();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `dialog.dismiss()` instead of `dialog.cancel();`.

Comment: Thank you, I could have sworn I had tried that before and it didn't help then.
It does work now.

Answer (score 0):

Instaed of    dialog.cancel()

use

dismissDialog();

dismissDialog() will contain self name as parameter.
check it.

Comment: It's saying that the id is -1 then that no dialog with that id was called.